# Proving convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \log(1 + \frac{1}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wonder if this is a valid proof that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$$
converges:

$$\frac{1}{n} \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) < \frac{1}{n} \log(1) = \frac{1}{n}\times0 = 0$$
And the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0 = 0$, therefore from the comparison test the sum from the title ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \log(1 + \frac{1}{n})$) converges.

Is this valid? I feel like I'm doing something forbidden here by comparing it with 0.

Comment: Huh? log (1 + 1/n) > log (1) =0.  Why on earth did you think log (1 + 1/n) < log (1)?  That doesn't make *any* sense.

Comment: Also terms < 0 doesn't mean it converges.  If all terms are negative it could diverge negatively.  And "comparison test" to what?  You have 0 as an *upper* limit but what's your lower limit?  Surely, you must have realized log (1 + 1/n) is positive?  So if you get log (1 + 1/n) < 0, you must have realism you were doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, I did realise it now that you've mentioned it. While solving this my mind was still at finding bounds for the denominators, where what I've written would hold true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not valid at all. For every $n$, the summands are positive - they aren't smaller than $0$.

And even if the first inequality was correct, the result wouldn't follow. $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} -1 $ is divergent, even though $-1 < 0$.

---

For an approach that works, recall that $\ln(1 + x) \approx x$ for $x$ small enough.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{n} \log(1 + \frac{1}{n}) < \frac{1}{n} \log(1)$$

This is not true. Plot a graph to see why.

If you want to prove convergence, perhaps try using this (just an idea - might not work):

$$\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)=\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$$

$$\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\log\left(n+1\right)-\log\left(n\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

hint: use $\log(1+x) \leq x$, with $x = \dfrac{1}{n}$, and the fact that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ converges as a $p$-series with $p > 1$

Answer (score 0):

As others have written, the inequality in the OP is not correct.  In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x}{x+1}\le \log(1+x)\le x} \tag 1$$

Now, letting $x=1/n$ in $(1)$, we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\le \frac1n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\le \frac1{n^2}} \tag 2$$

So, by the comparison test (or the integral test), the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)$ converges.

Note that we can even obtain from $(2)$ crude bounds for the value of the series of interest.  The left-hand side of $(2)$ can be written $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac1{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$, which is a telescoping sequence.  Therefore, the sum of the left-hand side is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1$.

The sum of the right-hand side was the [Basel Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), first solved by Euler in 1734.  The sum is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Putting it all together we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{1 \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\le \frac{\pi^2}{6}}$$