# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, logarithms

I am trying to check the convergence or divergence of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1n\log\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)$.

> My attempt:  for a finite
>   $p$,\begin{align}\displaystyle\sum_{k=n}^{n+p}\dfrac1k\log\left(1+\dfrac1k\right)&\lt\dfrac1n\displaystyle\sum_{k=n}^{n+p}\log\left(1+\dfrac1k\right)\\&=\dfrac1n\log\large\Pi_{k=n}^{n+p}\left(\dfrac{k+1}{k}\right)\\&=\dfrac1n\log\left(1+\dfrac{p+1}{n}\right)\\&\lt\dfrac1n\log2,\text{
>  for large $n$ and $p$ is finite.}\\&\lt\varepsilon\end{align}
>   Hence the series converges.

Comment: See also: [Proving convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \log(1 + \frac{1}{n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1696221). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac1n%5Clog%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cfrac1n%5Cright%24&p=1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $$\frac{\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n^2}}\rightarrow1$$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of the comparison test. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Getting the exact value of $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ is harder than showing the sum converges

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, but by the telescoping sum easy to see that the second sum converges.

Answer (score 3):

$a_n:= (1/n)\log (1+1/n);$

Recall : $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1+1/n)^n=e$.

Hence $(1+1/n)^n$ is bounded by  a $M$, real, positive.

Then $(1+1/n)^n <M$, and with

$\log (1+1/n)^n < \log M <M$:

$a_n = (1/n^2) \log(1+1/n)^n <M/n^2$.

Comparison test: $M \sum 1/n^2$ converges.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: Arjun.A pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is not correct. For the Cauchy criterion you have to show that
for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that
$$
 \sum_{k=n}^{n+p}\dfrac1k\log\left(1+\dfrac1k\right) < \varepsilon
$$
for all $n \ge N$ and **all** $p \ge 0$. So you can not “fix” $p$ and 
assume that
$$
\dfrac1n\log\left(1+\dfrac{p+1}{n}\right)\lt\dfrac1n\log2 \, .
$$

---

But using the “well-known” estimate [$\log x \le x-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222872/show-that-ln-x-leq-x-1)
one gets
$$
 0 \le \frac1n\log\left(1+\dfrac1n\right) \le \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
and that implies the convergence by the “squeeze theorem.”

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubts. But can't I avoid comparison test anyway?

Comment: @ArjunBanerjee: Well, you could write $\sum_{k=n}^{n+p}\frac1k\log\left(1+\frac1k\right) \le \sum_{k=n}^{n+p} \frac{1}{k^2} < \sum_{k=n}^{n+p} \frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \sum_{k=n}^{n+p} \left( \frac 1{k-1} - \frac 1k \right) = \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac 1{n+p} < \frac{1}{n-1}$ if that is what you are looking for. (But that essentially repeats the proof that $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent.)